# Right navbar is scrolling down

Tags: html, css

How to fix it? I am newbie in frontend :/
[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vz7Wl.png)
[After minimized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0AG5.png)
I am using w3-sidebar w3-bar-block w3-card class for it.

```html
      <div id ="menu" class="w3-sidebar w3-bar-block w3-card" style="width:13%;right:0;">
        <h3 class="w3-bar-item">Sort</h3>
        <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Price</a>
        <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Name</a>
        <div *ngIf="authService.isLogged"  class="cartItemsh">   <!--  -->
          <h3 class="w3-bar-item">Your cart: <b>${{ cartSum.toFixed(2) }}</b></h3>   <!-- cart -->
          <div  *ngFor="let item of cartItems"  class="cart"> <!--  -->
            <ul class="w3-bar-item" id="cartItems">
                  <div class="oneCartItem">
                      <li class="liItem">
                        <div class="nameCart">{{ item.name }}</div>
                        <span class="avatar"><img src="{{ item.imgurl }}" width="64px" height="64px"></span>
                        <span class="priceCart"><b> ${{ item.price }}</b></span>
                        <span class="quantCart">{{ item.quant }}</span>
                        <span class="removeItem"><img class="removeItemButton" src="{{ removeImage }}" title="Click to remove item" (click)="deleteFromCart(item.name)"></span>
                       </li>
                    </div>
            </ul>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Share your code please

Comment: I think that in order to help you, we need to see what you have got so far, eg: HTML, CSS etc. Please share them all and we'll try to help you ;)

Comment: I do not have any CSS connected to this div, because it's using https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css. I copied it and I thought it would work :( Added html code of this bar. :)

Comment: Could you please indicate which scenario do you need from here: [w3css_sidebar](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_sidebar.asp)

Comment: I have Right-sided Side Navigation, but after minimize browser it looks like I posted. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just replicated the W3S example which seems to work completely fine.
Please try to use it as below:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">


<div class="w3-sidebar w3-bar-block w3-card" style="width:25%;right:0;">
  <h3 class="w3-bar-item">Menu</h3>
  <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Link 3</a>
</div>

<div style="margin-right:25%">

<div class="w3-container w3-teal">
  <h1>My Page</h1>
</div>

<div class="w3-container">
<h2>Right Sidebar</h2>

</div>

</div>
```